# Selenium IDE export available in Ant / Java task for automated build

Tags: java, selenium, ant

If we export a selenium test case by using the IDE, it creates lovely Java code.

Would it be possible to use ant to auto-generate these tests into Java code, to integrate that into an automated build? Is that possible?

Or is it possible to run a test suite from an Ant task?